# Hide or remove column in Google Chart if rows are empty

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

In google chart (table is the chart type) how do I determine if rows in a column is empty and then hide that column?

for example:

`[Boys] [Girls]
 [ 1  ] [    ]
 [ 3  ] [    ]
 [ 3  ] [    ]`

*Girls* column is empty therefore hide or remove it, resulting in the table chart showing only the *Boys* column.

`[Boys]
 [ 1  ]
 [ 3  ]
 [ 3  ]`

**Here is a sample of my code:**

```
var datatable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

var rows = [
  {
    "Year": 2014,
    "Period": 3,
    "Segment": "*",
    "AnswerOption": 0,
    "AnswerValue": 5,
    "ResultCount": 2,
    "ResultAverage": 33.3333
  },
  {
    "Year": 2014,
    "Period": 4,
    "Segment": "*",
    "AnswerOption": 0,
    "AnswerValue": 5,
    "ResultCount": 5,
    "ResultAverage": 100.00
  }
]

datatable.addColumn('string', 'Year');
datatable.addColumn('number', 'Period');
datatable.addColumn('string', 'Segment');
datatable.addColumn('string', 'AnswerOption');
datatable.addColumn('number', 'AnswerValue');
datatable.addColumn('number', 'ResultCount');
datatable.addColumn('number', 'ResultAverage');


for(var j=0; j < rows.length; j++) {
datatable.addRows([
    [
        String(rows[j].Year),
        rows[j].Period,
        rows[j].Segment,
        rows[j].AnswerOption,
        rows[j].AnswerValue,
        rows[j].ResultCount,
        rows[j].ResultAverage,
    ]
 ]);    
}
```

In this example, all `AnswerOption` is `0` therefore google chart displays an empty cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse your DataTable and construct a DataView that contains only columns that are not empty:

```
// assumes you have a DataTable "data"
var columns = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < data.getNumberOfRows(); j++) {
        if (data.getValue(j, i) !== null) {
            // add the column to the array if we find a value in it
            columns.push(i);
            // break because we don't need to search this column any more
            break;
        }
    }
}
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
view.setColumns(columns);
```

then use `view` to draw your Table, instead of using the DataTable.

Comment: I used your code but it is showing only 1 column. Why is that?

Comment: Are your other columns empty?  If they are, it is doing exactly what you asked for in your question.  If they are not empty, can you update your question with a sample DataTable that reproduces the problem?

Comment: to be more specific on the error from your code, the chart is only showing numbers in sequential order, i.e: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6

Comment: Nevermind, it worked. I just misplaced your code, i placed it before the rows declaration. Now i placed it after everything and before drawing the chart.